# Why Window.pack() does not work when executed after Window.setVisible()?

Tags: java, swing

This the question about why such issue occurs and not how to fix it.

I was playing around with `JFrames` in Java and noticed that for me, window size doesn't adjust to it's contents if I put `pack()` after `setVisible(true)`, no matter where exactly I put those in respect to other lines of code. However it does work perfectly if I switch them so that `setVisible(true)` comes after `pack()`. Refer to the snippet below for an example.

Now, I've seen some answers there, not directly related to this, just mentioning that `pack()` should go before `setVisible()`, without any details why is this the case. Moreover, while I cannot test this for now myself, but based on what I've seen, I believe that this issue is not present on all platforms - I am using Kubuntu 20.10 and tried multiple OpenJDK versions.
What's also seems strange is that if I put `Thread.sleep(1000)` in `frame1()` just after `setVisible(true)`, the code works. So it looks like some timing issue. Also issue is not present when I am debugging and manually stepping over the lines.

So my question is, why I am experiencing this strange behavior? Has anyone encountered it? I haven't found any info about that online, although it seems like this issue could be quite annoying to debug if overlooked. I am new to Java graphics, so maybe my code is incorrect somewhere else?

Example code:

```java
public class MyClass {


    // Does not size correctly
    public void frame1(){
        int w = 100;
        int h = 100;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window 1");
        frame.setSize(w, h);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // Thread.sleep() here also fixes it.
        frame.pack();
    }
    // Works correctly
    public void frame2(){
        int w = 100;
        int h = 100;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window 2");
        frame.setSize(w, h);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.frame1();
        myClass.frame2();
    }
}
```

Output (incorrectly sized Window 1 on the left):

[image]

Edit: removed accidental duplicate call to `setVisible()` in the code.

EDIT: I wrapped the call to `frame1()` with `invokeAndWait()` and now I am getting correct sized window *sometimes*:

```java
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myClass.frame1();
                }
            });
```

But still only once in about 5 runs. So it looks like issue is not simply because of incorrect threads?

Comment: You might running into a thread race condition - in Swing, once the window has been realised (attach to a native peer), you should make all modifications on the Event Dispatching Thread.  Since calling `setVisible` does not result in an immediate showing of the window (ie - the method will return before the window is shown on the screen) and because you're updating the UI outside of the EDT, you could be a thread race condition

Comment: Also, your second frame also calls `setVisible` before `pack`, but it calls `setVisible` again.  I tested various approaches and had no issues.  I'd still recommend that you ensure all UI interactions are done on the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oops, that second `setVisible()` was unintentionally left from my testing. Because it calls it after `pack()` too, it works. Anyway, thread race condition makes sense, maybe still a little strange that it only happens for me (or only on some platforms) and so consistently.